# Error in importing DashProxy - Input is missing

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm trying to run a pre-written code that utilize Dash, but it raise an error in importing DashProxy:

`python from dash_extensions.enrich import DashProxy`

I got this error message:
[image]

I went to the source code of `enrich.py` and tried to move the import command over there this way:

```py
from dash import exceptions, resources, callback_context
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State, ClientsideFunction, MATCH, ALL, ALLSMALLER, no_updatedevelopment, dcc, html, dash_table, html, dash_table, callback, clientside_callback
```

I thought Input and other dependencies should be loaded from `dash.dependencies` but it seems like some of them are not even there. Now it raise error for importing a bunch of others:

[image]

I know it's not a good practice to change the source code of a library this way, but even with this hack type solution I can't get it to work.

Here's the versions of dash and dash_extension:

```
dash_extensions.__version__
'0.0.71'
dash.__version__
'1.20.0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors you see are because the version of `dash-extensions` is for Dash 2.0.0 (or newer). Hence you should either upgrade `dash` (preferred solution), or use an older version of `dash-extensions`.